# Trapped In A Glass Cube

Tags: lateral-thinking

You wake up and find yourself trapped in a glass square shaped covering. Luckily, you see soil below, unlike all the other directions. You start digging but find that there is glass at the bottom too. You are trapped in a glass cube. You are given a source of water and food. How will you escape?

Rules :-

> - You are not strong enough to break the glass
> - You are not strong enough to move the glass.
> - You have no source of external help.
> - You have nothing except your clothes.
> - You cannot use your clothes in any way to break the glass.
> - You cannot kill yourself and free your sprit. This does not count
> - You have unlimited time to live, but this does not mean you will get stronger.
> - There are no holes in the glass.
> - The food and water appears at your will, but you cannot use any other magic nor can anyone else. You can only summon food in the glass cube, and not outside
> - You cannot fill cube with water or food in hope to build pressure
> - The glass cannot melt.
> - You cannot use the stones in the soil to break the glass.
> - The worms and insects in the soil cannot chew through the glass.

Comment: I noticed that only some of the letters are oddly capitalized. Is this intentional?

Comment: how do you breath in a glass with no holes?

Comment: does the food I summon have to be edible?

Comment: @MKBakker Now I'm curious what you would suggest if it doesn't have to be edible?

Comment: @npkllr I replied in an answer to prevent spoilers

Comment: "You cannot fill cube with water or food in hope to build pressure" - but in this scenario, each day more matter is getting into the cube and nothing is getting out. "There are no holes in the glass". If the cube doesn't grow and there is no magical waste removal, pressure will build up.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you are talking about a covering on a glass base plate and not about a sealed glass cube closed all around? So the covering can be lifted, just not by me, because I'm not strong enough?

Comment: Given that the soil at the bottom is explicitly mentioned, then also appears in two of the rules, it must have something to do with the answer.

Comment: @KarstenKöpnick Actually you'll die of CO2 buildup long before your waste could break you out.  If you have all the time in the world, there must be some magical way to remove at least waste co2.  Or the cube is so big it has enough trees, water and grass to devour your co2 (in which case, I'm not sure I want to leave my cube at all!)

Comment: @BillK. I totally agree. I'm just nitpicking that the setup contradicts with the rule that you cannot build up pressure, since the setup alone will. - As for the CO2 and the breathing needs of the cubed person, we have no information on the nature of the food. If it's not just pulp of nutrients but whole fruits, maybe planting is a given here. Might sustain oxygen levels for a while. - Even if your cube has enough trees, water and grass, it has no Internet connection. Sure you wanna stay just for the trees? ;-)

Comment: uhm... the accepted answer is an actual pun-based joke? what kind of puzzle is this?

Comment: @KarstenKöpnick I live in USA, at this point I wouldn't mind getting "away from it all" for a few hundred years.  Plus I get to live forever as long as I'm in the cube!

Comment: @BillK A sad but understandable point.

Comment: @Sebastianb That is the point of the lateral thinking tag.

Comment: @KhushrajRathod Maybe you should consider adding the humor tag then

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You could

> summon an apple, break it in half, put the halves together to make a whole, climb through the whole to escape, shout until your voice is hoarse, climb on the hoarse and ride home.

EDIT:

> If you wanna add some extra steps, you could plant the apple, grow a tree, punch the tree until your hand is sore, use the sore(saw) to chop the tree in half and then put those halves together to make a whole.

Comment: oh my literal goodness

Comment: This just made my day

Comment: Have you considered crafting a canoe from the tree, summoning a thousand cups of tomato soup to make a river, riding the river to the other side of the cube where you then cut the canoe in half, put the halves together to make a whole and use the whole to climb out?

Comment: +1 Loved Your Answer

Comment: Wait was this the intended answer? I put it as a joke lol, and got the most amount of upvotes I've ever gotten

Comment: It's a *very old* joke...

Comment: Yeah I've heard it as a riddle of being in a room with no windows or door and only having a plank of wood

Comment: I think you can only use the sore if you're from Boston.

Comment: @rrauenza or England like I am

Answer (score 35):

Since:

> As is, the glass is too strong to break, I need to weaken it.

So, first:

> I summon freezing cold water (aka ice, I guess, or just really cold water)

Then:

> Put the ice (or pour the cold water) a certain spot on the glass to chill it.

While simultaneously:

> Summoning some boiling water, as hot as I can

And:

> I pour the boiling water on the specific location on the glass. Done in quick enough succession, this should cause the glass to break/crack, at least at the spot, making it weak enough to easily break.

Comment: I think that's the first answer that is actually possible, does not break any rule and you don't have to wait for million years to get out of the cube.

Comment: I like this one!

Comment: @npkllr sometimes breaking the rules is more interesting though ;-)

Comment: This should be the answer!

Answer (score 19):

Hmm, maybe you could

> summon apple (or any other tree-fruit) and plant its seeds, water it with the water you can also summon and wait for it to actually grow until it can't fit in the glass cube anymore. You'd be surprised with the force of nature :)

Comment: Don't forget using your own special brand of natural fertilizer!

Comment: Lol :) that's disgusting!

Comment: If my assumption that part of the glass prison can be lifted is correct, than this is a perfectly feasible solution.

Comment: @KarstenKöpnick it doesn't need to be lifted - trees can get through many things if needs be. It will take a lot of time, sure, but the puzzle mentions this is not an issue.

Comment: @Asunez: You are right. We have no information on the strength of the glass other than that the prisoner cannot break it. But we have no information on the size and weight of the cube either. We can take a guess at all of it, but with that level of uncertainty I have no basis for estimating that having a tree lift the alleged cover is more feasible than having it break the cube. So my assumption is not necessary for your approach to be what the OP had in mind.

Comment: The prisoner might live forever, but an apple tree won't.

Answer (score 16):

I'd summon

> my mother-in-law's fruitcake. It's hard enough to cut glass.

Answer (score 12):

If you have

> Unlimited time to live and a constant supply of food and water, I’d simply recommend waiting. Glass takes anywhere from 4000 to 1 million years to decompose; wait out that length of time and then you’ll be free!

Either that, or you could

> More jokingly eat and eat and eat until your mass breaks the glass down; but if it’s a big enough cube this won’t work ;p

Comment: You're too tricky mate :D

Comment: Could get boring after some time, but I still like your answer :)

Comment: Haha thanks both! Might need to summon some video games too...

Comment: You beat me too it!  i like this answer too.

Answer (score 9):

I am

> a cannibal, so I summon a feast of 100 men inside the cube. We use our collective strength to lift/break the cube. To celebrate, I eat them.

Comment: (+1) Disturbing, but viable

Answer (score 8):

I would

> Summon a donut, eat the outside and use the hole to exit

Comment: This answer is even cruller than the other one!     :-)    ⁠

Answer (score 7):

What about...

> Use your voice to match the glass's high-pitched natural resonance tone to produce vibrations strong enough to shatter the glass. Perhaps some high-pitched opera style singing?

Answer (score 6):

- Idea no. 1, I would

> summon a sledgehammer and a screwdriver (2 cocktails) and smash my way out.

- Idea no. 2, (similar to another answer) based on the clue

> Luckily, you see soil below

So I would

> summon bamboo shoots, and plant them, and they will grow and break the box.

- Idea no. 3, (similar to another answer) based on the condition

> You can only summon food in the glass cube, and not outside

which might deliberately imply that

> You can summon water outside the glass cube

and so I would summon

> flambé dishes to heat the ceiling fom the inside and water to cool the glass from the outside

Comment: Worth a try in any case. If it doesn't work, you'll at least have a fine evening.

Comment: You can only summon food :|

Comment: Summon Molotov cocktail

Comment: @WaisKamal: all of his suggestions are food. Maybe by a stretch, but the nature of the food has not been defined.

Comment: @YoutRied username checks out.

Comment: I like the bamboo shoots idea.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you can

> wait a million years or so (since you have Unlimited Time to Live) and the glass should decay back into sand eventually.

If puns are allowed (and really, should puns ever be allowed?)

> you could try harder and harder until you are going all out.  And there you are!

Comment: Unfortunately, El-Guest has already answered the same thing first lol :)

Comment: Great minds think alike!! Nice answer :D

Answer (score 3):

Well, one way to get out is

> Summon a lot of food in the glass's thickness (I don't know whether this still counts as summoning food inside the glass cube). This will create a hole big enough after removing the food. You can then get out :)

Answer (score 3):

I would

> develop Pica, and then gradually call small parts of the glass cube for me to eat.  Eventually, a hole will develop in the wall which I can easily walk out of.

Answer (score 3):

I would:

> Create Sodium Hydroxide to dissolve the glass

How:

> Summon a some salt and water, mix. Then summon some potatoes. I would then use the wire in a bra or belt buckle to create electrodes in the potatoes and begin to create NaOH.

Then:

> Summon tree bark (yes it can be editable) to create a fire. Boil off the remaining water and voila, you have Sodium Hydroxide! Let the dissolving commence!

After Thoughts:

> I really think the Capital Letters mean something, perhaps Give a clue to a cryptogram of sorts. Something to ponder over..

Comment: I was going along these lines as well but with Hydroflouric acid.  I figured some sort of foodstuffs would be able to make but the only ways I saw to make it were from minerals.

Answer (score 3):

2 easy ways:

> Since the question doesn't say that I am a normal human, I can use my Speedster skills (I am the Flash) to either
>  1. Vibrate so fast that I can pass through the glass walls in a process called quantum tunneling
>
> or
>
> 2. Travel through time by running faster than light to when I wasn't in the glass box (you said I woke up in the box).
>
>
> Also, this isn't any magic, it's science.
> After I escape, I will summon lots of food and water since I get hungry after using my Speed Force.

Answer (score 2):

In lieu of a more reasonable answer I came up with this -

> make gunpowder with your urine

Thought process -

> So the main issue I have with a lot of these ideas is the thought that you can summon a specific type of food and specific temperature of water to escape from the cube.  I however believe the answer lies within the body, the only constant inside the cube.  Urine and feces can always be produced by the body regardless of the nutrients that enter it.  Using a bit of chemistry and ingenuity urine can be made into a rudimentary gunpowder and likely the rocks within the nitrogen rich soil can be used as an ignition source.  Given infinite time I don't think this is an unreasonable solution.

Link to a video explaining the process -

> https://www.reddit.com/r/videos/comments/5ff6q6/making_gunpowder_from_urine_codyslab/

Answer (score 1):

You've got to wear away the glass somehow; fortunately, you can

> summon various acids to weaken this (nice glass of lemon juice, anybody? Maybe some vinegar). You'll need a rubbing cloth to work this against a patch of glass - if you can't use your clothes, just painstakingly weave a cloth from your own hair. Give it a decade or two and you'll surely be out.

Inspiration: the 'unbreakable' prison in the Lightbringer books - [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Blinding_Knife)

Comment: Lemon juice or vinegar doesn't do much to glass. Nothing at all, in fact...

Answer (score 1):

I would

> define everything on the other side of the glass as being "enclosed by the largest cube in the universe" and thus free myself from being trapped INSIDE the cube.

Comment: This sounds more like magic, which is not allowed. You should consider taking the [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn how the site works.

Comment: @HerbWolfe: This sounds more like maths, which is allowed but doesn't help here. It's just an old topology joke. Invert your space at the walls of your cell and you're free. - How to catch a lion? Topologist: Brings a cage to the desert. Inverts the desert space at the walls of the cage  Then the lion is in the cage.

Comment: Sounds like the first solution [*here*](http://www.columbia.edu/~sss31/rainbow/catch.lion.html).

Answer (score 0):

> I would make some edible which can cause corrosion of the glass and with a branch(from which the chemical is extracted) will break the glass and escape the cube.

Comment: Please try to come up with something more specific than this.

Answer (score 0):

Look a serious answer!

> Summon toothpaste and a lemon. Combine the lemon and toothpaste to create small amounts of HF, which should dissolve through the glass walls.

Comment: Can you really create hydroflouric acid with toothpaste and a lemon?

Comment: @TracyCramer, yes just not in large quantities. But with enough toothpaste and enough lemons you could hypothetically eat through the glass.

Comment: I wonder why someone downvoted it...

Answer (score 0):

Escape?  I challenge this notion.  I'm not trapped at all.

> I'm fine where I am.  What you have given me is a giant hamster ball
>
>  [image: Hampster ball]

Indeed, people pay money for this!

> [image: Hampster cube]

But at some point, I'm going to be asked to actually solve the puzzle.

> It says I'm not strong enough to move the cube, but some movements don't call for strength.  Mass is enough.  And the puzzle never stated the cube's size nor orientation.  If I find myself in a large cube that's on edge, rather than lying flat, I could summon a large amount of food in one of the raised edges... say lots of caramel so it sticks to the glass.  That mass could rotate the cube until it lands.  Large sheets of glass break.  You can make them as thick as you like.
>
>  If that's not good enough, you can always take advantage of momentum.   Since I can't build up pressure in the room, there must be a way that unsummons the food when it gets to be too much.  Unsummon the food in one corner once you're past 90 degrees, then summon it in the next corner.  You can build up an arbitrary amount of speed that way.

That glass is going down, one way or another.  But honestly... hamsterball.

> [image: XKCD]